# Word2Vec/Doc2vec + K-Means clustering - how to extract "semantically meaningful" centroids?

Tags: python, text, nlp, word-embedding

I have a list of unique terms, say for example:

```
['Dollars','Cash','International Currency','Credit card','Comics','loans','David Beckham','soccer','Iron Man','checks','Euros','World Cup','Marvel Cinematic Universe','Champions league','Superman']
```

Ultimately I want to achieve the following mapping:

```
['Dollars','Cash','International Currency','Credit card','loans','checks','Euros','World']: 'Money and finance'

['Comics','Iron Man','Marvel Cinematic Universe','Superman']: 'Comics and Superherores'

['David Beckham','soccer','World Cup','Champions league']: 'Soccer, Football'
```

My idea is to use a text embedding like word2vec or doc2vec, and then cluster the embeddings using K-Means. So far this is very straightforward. But then I would like to map the resulting embedding centroids to 2 or 3 relevant terms. Is there a way to go from the numerical embedding centroid to semantically meaningful terms?

If there is a better way to do this other than `Embedding > Clustering > Extract meaning from centroid` I could try that as well.

A couple of things to note about this is that: The terms in my lists are unique - either individual words, compound terms, or vert short sentences, not paragraphs or documents - so frequency or word count based methods are not applicable. And the lists also contain a lot of noise, e.g. "xxx thx u" and "Hello Mr. Johnson", etc...

So my two asks are:

- What is the best way to achieve this mapping?
- And how can we map a centroid from an embedding space to a small set of meaningful terms?

Comment: one way to do it is to average embeddings in the cluster and get the closest term. Another one is to get the most common term from the cluster. There is no recognized standard for this, so whatever sounds reasonable for the reviewers